# Comparing "axiomatized function spaces"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, logic, universal-algebra

Let $C(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ be the space$^1$ of all continuous functions $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I'm interested in analyzing subspaces of $C(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ determined by first-order theories, especially finite equational theories. Specifically, for $T$ a set of first-order sentences in the language of a single binary operation, let $T_\mathbb{R}$ be the subspace of continuous $f$ such that $(\mathbb{R};f)\models T$. I'm curious about how $T$ affects the purely topological properties of $T_\mathbb{R}$. For example, when is $T_\mathbb{R}$ connected? etc.

However, even in very concrete cases, I'm having trouble understanding what $T_\mathbb{R}$ looks like. Letting $C$ and $A$ be the usual statements of commutativity and associativity, I think an answer to the following question would clear things up immensely:

> **Question**: is $\{C\}_\mathbb{R}\cong\{A\}_\mathbb{R}$?

The answer really **should** be negative - these are very different properties - but I don't see how to get started.

*(Actually, I'm interested in general $C(X^2,X)$ and not just $X=\mathbb{R}$, but this special case seems already very interesting on its own.)*

---

$^1$With respect to the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology). That said, if there's some other natural topology on $C(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ (like pointwise-convergence) which gives an interesting answer, I'd be happy with that too.

Comment: Quick observation: $\{C\}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a vector subspace of $C(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ and so is a topological vector space, which tells you a lot about its topological properties (e.g, it is contractible).

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, I should have mentioned that! Really it's $\{A\}_\mathbb{R}$ which confuses me - I don't really know any good structure that it has.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am not so convinced that the answer should be negative--it seems quite plausible to me that they are homeomorphic just because there is so much "room" in infinite-dimensional spaces to build homeomorphisms. (For instance, any two separable infinite-dimensional Banach spaces are homeomorphic, and also homeomorphic to their unit spheres.)  But I agree that $\{A\}_\mathbb{R}$ seems hard to get a handle on; the best idea I've come up with is thinking about the action of homeomorphisms $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by conjugation.